# Commutative and Associative properties on residue classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $Z_n$ denote the residue classes modulo n.

How would I prove that $Z_n$ is associative and commutative?

Any tips/help appreciated. I found a proof that the integers is commutative and associative, is there an easy step to just add to this one?

Comment: For integers, $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$ and $a + b = b + a$. As these two things are the same numbers, reducing modulo $n$ would give you same residues too.

Comment: You haven't defined what is the operation you're interested in. addition? multiplication?